# jQuery easyui edatagrid onLoadSuccess fires twice

Tags: datagrid, jquery-easyui

I use jQuery easyui, and the extension Editable DataGrid named edatagrid, which extendes from jQuery easyui datagrid.
you can download the edatagrid file this page:
http://www.jeasyui.com/extension/edatagrid.php
Then I modified the editable-datagrid.html, add handler for onBeforeLoad and onLoadSuccess event, and a button to reload json data. my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery EasyUI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../themes/icon.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.edatagrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            //$('#tt').datagrid({
            $('#tt').edatagrid({
                onBeforeLoad: function(param){
                    console.log("before load");
                }, 
                onLoadSuccess: function(data){
                    console.log("load success");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Editable DataGrid</h1>
    <div style="margin-bottom:10px">
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:$('#tt').edatagrid('addRow')">AddRow</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:$('#tt').edatagrid('saveRow')">SaveRow</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:$('#tt').edatagrid('cancelRow')">CancelRow</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:$('#tt').edatagrid('destroyRow')">destroyRow</a>
        <a onclick="javascript:$('#tt').edatagrid('reload')">reload</a>
    </div>
    <table id="tt" style="width:600px;height:200px"
            title="Editable DataGrid"
            url="datagrid_data.json"
            singleSelect="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th field="itemid" width="100" editor="{type:'validatebox',options:{required:true}}">Item ID</th>
                <th field="productid" width="100" editor="text">Product ID</th>
                <th field="listprice" width="100" align="right" editor="{type:'numberbox',options:{precision:1}}">List Price</th>
                <th field="unitcost" width="100" align="right" editor="numberbox">Unit Cost</th>
                <th field="attr1" width="150" editor="text">Attribute</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Open editable-datagrid.html in chrome or firefox, check console log:

before load 
load success 
Object {total: 0, rows: Array[0]} 
load success 
Object {total: 10, rows: Array[10]}

click reload button to reload edatagrid, get the same result.

before load 
load success 
Object {total: 10, rows: Array[10]} 
load success 
Object {total: 10, rows: Array[10]}

Why onBeforeLoad event fired once, but onLoadSuccess event fired twice, it also should be once. How can I make the onBeforeLoad event fires just one time?

if I use datagrid, both of onBeforeLoad and onLoadSuccess fire once.

before load 
load success 
Object {total: 10, rows: Array[10]}

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason 
there is a onBeforeLoad handler in jquery.edatagrid.js

```
onBeforeLoad: function(param){
                if (opts.onBeforeLoad.call(target, param) == false){return false}
                $(this).datagrid('rejectChanges');
                if (opts.tree){
                    var node = $(opts.tree).tree('getSelected');
                    param[opts.treeParentField] = node ? node.id : undefined;
                }
            }
```

rejectChanges will reload the datagrid, so onLoadSuccess fired twice.

Comment: ok, you found the reason, can you tell us what you did to solve it ?

Comment: then you need to accept your answer so that the others who read this question get the attention that this already answered

Answer (score 0):

you typed:

```
$('#tt').edatagrid({
```

and it is:

```
$('#tt').datagrid({
```